# Diferenças entre utilizar typecast e wrapper class?

Tags: java

Olá, a proposta de atividade seria mostrar quantos anos o usuário teria, eu escrevi meu código primeiro para depois poder comparar com o do professor, acontece que minha primeira linha saiu bem menor que a do professor.

Esse é o meu código:

```
int an = (int) txtAN.getValue();    // an (ano de nascimento), pega o valor de um spinner
int ran = 2017 - an;    // ran (resultado do ano de nascimento)
lblIdade.setText(Integer.toString(ran));    // mostra no label o valor recebido
```

Esse é o do professor:

```
int an = Integer.parseInt(txtAN.getValue().toString());
int id = 2017 - an;
lblIdade.setText(Inteer.toString(id));
```

1. Quais são os pros e contras de utilizar o `typecast` (como no meu
   caso), ou utilizar a `wrapper class` (como no caso do professor)?
2. Qual método está "correto" ou "errado"? Por quê?

Obs: É um projeto utilizando Swing.

Comment: No fim, ambos vao virar int ou lançar exceção se não for possivel, não vejo diferença. Alias, na minha opinião, nenhuma das duas formas é "correta", o recomendável, já que se trata de um spinner numérico, é passar um SpinnerNumberModel, que dispensa qualquer cast para integer ao resgatar o getvalue.

Comment: Poderia fazer um exemplo de como usar o SpinnerNumberModel? Não entendi.

Comment: De fato os dois estão errados, ainda que fizesse desta forma, teria que tratar a exceção, que eu acho horrível, mas o Java prefere fazer coisas horríveis, então é a única opção se realmente quiser receber texto.

Comment: Então eu teria que realmente usar o SpinnerNumberModel? Isso que você quis dizer?